# Upload to heroku rails app with file path string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to upload a file to my rails app by sending the user's local location of the file via a parameter, so the input URL would look like this:

http://rails-app.herokuapp.com/element?file=C:\temp\data.txt

It's easy if I'm working on my local machine, since I can just use File.read(filename), however this doesn't work on heroku. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all Heroku has read-only file system. So you can't upload anything directly to heroku.
Use something like Amazon S3 to keep files.

The second issue is your approach. 
When running app locally - it has access to your C:/ drive.
But app that is located at remote server does not have access to your computers C:/ drive, so it can't fetch file.
You should upload either through browser file field or through passing accessible to anyone http link.

Comment: its simply a text file with a list of new entries to the database, the file doesn't need to be saved, just read. I know this has to be possible, because somehow rails is doing it in the background when you upload a file in the form helper file_field.

Comment: when you upload a file via form helper - your browser sends file content in POST request. But here you are passing filepath via GET. And the server can't get access to your computers hard drive.

Comment: Thanks, that actually pointed me in the right direction, I had to figure out how post requests worked, but ultimately was able to get around this issue